# Kia Rio 2006 jb cv starter circuit fault

Tags: starter, kia, rio

My car started making grinding noises which I found out was the starter motor engaging through the clutch switch being pushed in as I changed gear. I removed it from the clutch pedal and only pushed it in when I started the car. Now if I turn the key to start and press the clutch button in it will try to start without turning the key to the start position.
Starter motor solenoid seems to not engage all of the time but after a few times it will engage.
Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

The description is a bit confusing - let me see if I got this right: 
As soon as you press the switch on your clutch pedal (now wired to a separate button) the starter engages (with or without the key turned to start position)?

This sounds like there is a short circuit in the ignition switch wiring (and it's trying to crank the starter all the time, the only thing preventing it from being on all the time being your safety switch on the clutch pedal).

Open up the steering column covers and see if there's physical damage to the wiring. If not, disconnect the ignition switch and see if the problem is still there. If it's not, it's likely the ignition switch.